# Javascript - How to loop to print html element id in sorted number?

Tags: javascript, html

Hello Sorry for Beginner question. 
I want to print the html element id  or name  in loop number like this

```
<button id="foo1" name="foo1>foo</button>
<button id="foo2" name="foo2">foo</button>
<button id="foo3" name="foo3">foo</button>
................
<button id="foo10" name="foo10">foo</button>
```

for me it work if I use the PHP language to for loop

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 10 ;$i++) { ?>
    <button id="foo<?php echo $i; ?>"> <?php } ?>
```

But some case, I have to make loop in javascript language.I try this

```
    var i;
    for(i=1; i<=10; i++)
    {
var newspan = document.createElement('span');
    newspan.innerHTML = 'button id="foo + i"' ;
 document.getElementById('product').appendChild(newspan);
    }
```

but not work.

Comment: try changing `id="foo + i"` to `id="foo"+i` because all the id's would be `fooi` if you didn't.

Comment: `newspan.innerHTML = 'button id="foo"+i';`

Comment: Use this: `newspan.innerHTML = '<button id="foo' + i+'">Foo</button>' ;`

Comment: @KevinKloet id will be `foo + i` not `fooi`

Comment: @Mahi you're right, I made a mistake there, unfortunately i can no longer edit the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not appending an HTML tag, just the word button, try...

HTML:

```
<div id="product">    
</div>
```

JS:

```
for(var i=1; i<=10; i++) {
    var newspan = document.createElement('span');
    var currentFoo = 'foo' + i;
    newspan.innerHTML = '<button id="'+ currentFoo + '">' + currentFoo + '</button>';
    document.getElementById('product').appendChild(newspan);
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bigalreturns/ng1nbbod/)